# Cannot run older android studio project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-datepicker, better-pickers

I am trying to run an older project. But two libraries are causing `Resource entry xxx already defined` error." among other errors. Tried cleaning, clearing cache and invalidating etc. nothing helps. I looked into exploded aar in intermediates but couldn't seem to find any duplicates

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bondstein.sakibulalam.trackmyvehicle.trackmyvehicle"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('eu.inmite.android.lib:android-validation-komensky:0.9.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.4.0@aar'
    compile ("com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.5")
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile ('com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2')
    {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.4.0'
    compile 'eu.inmite.android.lib:android-styled-dialogs:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.codechimp-org.apprater:library:1.0.+'
}
```

**Full error:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDoomonafireballBetterpickersLibrary155Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubCodechimpOrgAppraterLibrary1028Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubFlavienlaurentDatetimepickerLibrary002Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4323Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeKeyboardsurferAndroidWidgetCrouton184Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareEuInmiteAndroidLibAndroidStyledDialogs120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda240Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgJrafAndroidSwitchBackport140Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker\library\0.0.2\res\values-sw600dp-land\values.xml
Error:(1) Resource entry ampm_label_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry ampm_left_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry date_picker_header_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry footer_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry header_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry left_side_width is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry separator_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry time_label_right_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry time_label_size is already defined.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.doomonafireball.betterpickers\library\1.5.5\res\values-sw600dp-land-v13\values.xml
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker\library\0.0.2\res\values-sw600dp\values.xml
Error:(1) Resource entry ampm_label_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry ampm_left_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry date_picker_component_width is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry date_picker_header_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry date_picker_header_text_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry date_picker_view_animator_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry day_number_select_circle_radius is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry day_number_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry extra_time_label_margin is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry footer_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry header_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry minimum_margin_sides is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry minimum_margin_top_bottom is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_day_label_text_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_label_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_list_item_header_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_list_item_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_list_item_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry month_select_circle_radius is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry picker_dimen is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_calendar_layout_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_day_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_month_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_year_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry separator_padding is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry time_label_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry year_label_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry year_label_text_size is already defined.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.doomonafireball.betterpickers\library\1.5.5\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values.xml
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker\library\0.0.2\res\values-w270dp-h560dp\values.xml
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_calendar_layout_height is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_day_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_month_size is already defined.
Error:(1) Resource entry selected_date_year_size is already defined.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.doomonafireball.betterpickers\library\1.5.5\res\values-w270dp-h560dp-v13\values.xml
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
Error:(1, 1) Originally defined here.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values-v9\themes.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabStyle'.
Error:(32, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarWidgetTheme'.
Error:(12, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionDropDownStyle'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeBackground'.
Error:(16, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeCloseButtonStyle'.
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeSplitBackground'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropDownListViewStyle'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupMenuStyle'.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values-v11\themes.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(16, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(33, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarWidgetTheme'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeSplitBackground'.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabStyle'.
Error:(27, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarWidgetTheme'.
Error:(12, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionDropDownStyle'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeBackground'.
Error:(16, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeCloseButtonStyle'.
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeSplitBackground'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropDownListViewStyle'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupMenuStyle'.
Error:(34, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values-v14\themes.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values-v14\styles.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
I:\Projects\track-my-vehicle\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundSplit'.
Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundStacked'.
Error:(27, 29) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'icon'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'progressBarStyle'.
Error:(29, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'titleTextStyle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'progressBarStyle'.
Error:(40, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackground'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(72, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropDownListViewStyle'.
Error:(71, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupMenuStyle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.377 secs
Information:134 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```